# Multiple image upload and preview of image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, filereader

I have created single upload for image and put image to canvas http://jsfiddle.net/StJnY/. Now I want to modify my script for multiple upload images, and this my modify script :

JS :

```
$(function () {
    $('#file-input').on('change', function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        if (!e.target.files.length || !window.FileReader) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var countedfiles = $('#thumbnails canvas[data-other="fileCanvas"]').length; // check lenght of file canvas
            for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
                if (countedfiles > 0) {
                    var numb = countedfiles + 1;
                } else {
                    var numb = i;
                }
                console.log(e.target.files[i]);
                var file = e.target.files[i];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = fileOnload(numb, e);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }

    });

    function fileOnload(numb, e) {
        var $img = $('<img>', {
            src: e.target.result
        });
        var newCanvas = '<canvas class="canvas" width="120px" height="120px" data-other="fileCanvas" id="canvas-' + numb + '"></canvas>';
        $('#thumbnails').append(newCanvas);
        var canvas = $('#canvas-' + numb)[0];

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        $img.load(function () {
            var maxWidth = 120; // Max width for the image
            var maxHeight = 120; // Max height for the image
            var ratio = 0; // Used for aspect ratio
            var width = this.width; // Current image width
            var height = this.height; // Current image height


            // Check if the current width is larger than the max
            if (width > maxWidth) {
                ratio = maxWidth / width; // get ratio for scaling image
                this.width = maxWidth; // Set new width
                this.height = height * ratio; // Scale height based on ratio
                height = height * ratio; // Reset height to match scaled image
            }

            var width = this.width; // Current image width
            var height = this.height; // Current image height

            // Check if current height is larger than max
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
                this.height = maxHeight; // Set new height
                this.width = width * ratio; // Scale width based on ratio
                width = width * ratio; // Reset width to match scaled image
            }
            var newWidth = this.width;
            var newHeight = this.height;
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        });

    }
});
```

But `e.target.result` is undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/StJnY/3/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have resolved. http://jsfiddle.net/StJnY/5/

1. `e.target.result` undefined because `e` will get callback from parent function. So I put defining variable `$img` like this :

   ```
   $('#file-input').on('change', function (evt) {
    // other stuff here.....

     reader.onload = function(e) { 
      var $img = $('<img>', {
       src: e.target.result
      });
     fileOnload(numb, $img);
     }

   });
   ```
2. For effisien if possible loop is really big, so I'm defining every iteration not using an anonymous function.

   ```
   $(function () {
     $('#file-input').on('change', function (evt) {

       if (!this.files.length || !window.FileReader) {
           return false;
       } else {
           var countedfiles = $('#thumbnails canvas[data-other="fileCanvas"]').length; // check lenght of file canvas
           console.log(countedfiles);
           for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
               if (countedfiles > 0) {
                   var numb = countedfiles;
               } else {
                   var numb = i;
               }
               setup_reader(numb, this.files[i]);
           }
       }

   });

   function setup_reader(numb, file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = function(e) { 
           var $img = $('<img>', {
               src: e.target.result
           });
           fileOnload(numb, $img);
       }
   }

   function fileOnload(numb, $img) {

       var newCanvas = '<canvas class="canvas" width="120px" height="120px" data-other="fileCanvas" id="canvas-' + numb + '"></canvas>';
       $('#thumbnails').append(newCanvas);
       var canvas = $('#canvas-' + numb)[0];

       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

       $img.load(function () {
           var maxWidth = 120; // Max width for the image
           var maxHeight = 120; // Max height for the image
           var ratio = 0; // Used for aspect ratio
           var width = this.width; // Current image width
           var height = this.height; // Current image height


           // Check if the current width is larger than the max
           if (width > maxWidth) {
               ratio = maxWidth / width; // get ratio for scaling image
               this.width = maxWidth; // Set new width
               this.height = height * ratio; // Scale height based on ratio
               height = height * ratio; // Reset height to match scaled image
           }

           var width = this.width; // Current image width
           var height = this.height; // Current image height

           // Check if current height is larger than max
           if (height > maxHeight) {
               ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
               this.height = maxHeight; // Set new height
               this.width = width * ratio; // Scale width based on ratio
               width = width * ratio; // Reset width to match scaled image
           }
           var newWidth = this.width;
           var newHeight = this.height;
           context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
       });

     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fabric js. You can upload multiple image on canvas.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
```